# Raspberry Pi boot error after restoring from image

Tags: boot, filesystem, image, backup

a few days ago my raspberry started to have problems while running which pointed to a defect file system. So I wanted to restore it with an image I made before one week, when everything worked fine. I created these images with Roadkil's Disk Image. But now, when I boot with the restored image, I get some errors on the booting screen (see screenshot 1-4). After some minutes, it ends up in a loop (see screenshot 5).
Do you have any advice?

Screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6c8na0x-YXxRGd1VDlSUjJ1Wms&usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like the OS cannot create the `/tmp` directory. Probably not enough space? If you trimmed the partitions and images to fit perfectly

Answer (score 1):

It seems your SD Card has left its life time. Restoring a backup to it doesn't make much sense. Use a new SD Card to restore the backup to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try burning the image again, and make sure you expand the filesystem. This sounds like a corrupt filesystem or a corrupt SD card.